# Python PanelOLS different statistics with single categorical and multiple dummy columns

Tags: python, pandas, regression, linear-regression, linearmodels

I am trying to balance check on a Pandas DataFrame using an OLS with entity fixed effects. An example DataFrame is below:

| county | year | treatment_vs_control | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jefferson | 2022 | 1 | 24 | M |
| Jackson | 2022 | 1 | 31 | M |
| Jefferson | 2022 | 0 | 28 | F |
| Jackson | 2022 | 1 | 24 | null |
| Adams | 2022 | 0 | 72 | F |

First I try to run the model with the gender field as-is.

```
model_as_is = PanelOLS.from_formula(
    formula="treatment_vs_control ~ age + gender + EntityEffects",
    data=df
).fit()

model_as_is.summary
```

I get an F statistics of ~3.05 with a p value of 0.0001.

Then, I try to run the model with one-hot encoded dummy gender columns. The DataFrame looks like below:

| county | year | treatment_vs_control | age | gender_m | gender_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jefferson | 2022 | 1 | 24 | 1 | 0 |
| Jackson | 2022 | 1 | 31 | 1 | 0 |
| Jefferson | 2022 | 0 | 28 | 0 | 1 |
| Jackson | 2022 | 1 | 24 | 0 | 0 |
| Adams | 2022 | 0 | 72 | 0 | 1 |

My model now looks like:

```
model_dummy = PanelOLS(
    dependent = df["treatment_vs_control"], 
    exog = df[["age", "gender"]], 
    entity_effects=True, 
    time_effects=False,
).fit()

model_dummy.summary
```

My F statistic is now ~2.61 with a p value of 0.0002.

If I try to simply keep a single gender column but make it numeric instead of string-type, I get even a third statistical breakdown.

Why might this happen?

Comment: Perhaps `from_formula` drops `null` values by default. Which are your `entity_effects` by the way? Your sample data does not seem to have an index.

Comment: Can you open an issue on the linearmodels github tracker?